# How to select text till first character?

Tags: vim

I want to replace text before first ':' in following text:

```
S No. 1: This is main text having a colon (:) in it.
```

I want above to get converted to:

```
This is main text having a colon (:) in it.
```

I used following code in vim:

```
s/\v.+://
```

However, it converts above text to:

```
) in it.
```

How can I remove part before first colon (:)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using the Any Character Character,`.`, with a Greedy Quantifier Does not Help You**

I just changed the greedy quantifier, `\+`, with a non-greedy quantifier, `\{-1,}`, which looks to match at least once in a non-greedy manner.

I just used this ex command:

`:s/^.\{-1,}:/`

Explanation:

`^` Start of line anchor

`.` Any non-end of line character

`\{-1,}` non-greedy quantifier (at least 1 instance of pattern). If you anticipate scenarios where there might not be any occurences, the quantifier, `\{-}`, would be more accurate (and shorter...credit to Peter Rinkler).

[image]

If you look in help, `:help greedy`, you will find a nice explanation on how to perform non-greedy searches.

---

Peter Rinckler also suggested that you could just create a non-colon character class such as `[^:]` in lieu of `.` (the any character except end of line character) and use the `*` quantifier (0 or more instances of the character class).

This is how this substitute ex command would look:

`:%s/^[^:]*://`

Comment: You can shorten that to `\{-}`, e.g. `:%s/^.\{-}//`. I also find using a negated character class to be good, `[^:]`, e.g. `:%s/^[^:]*://`.

Comment: @Peter Rincker, agreed.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `:s` command, you can also do it using `:normal` command:

```
:%norm! df:
```

Or macro, on the first line, press:

```
qq0df:j@qq
```

Then press `@q`

Comment: These solutions look interesting and simpler. It will be of great help if you could explain these codes.